# how does bi-directional differential signalling work?

Tags: lvds, bidirectional

I've always thought that differential signalling was a single-sender, single-receiver, one direction architecture.

However, I've come across [an SDRAM chip](http://download.micron.com/pdf/datasheets/dram/ddr2/1GbDDR2.pdf) where DQS strobes are differential and bidirectional:

[image: datasheet]

How exactly does this work? Particularly line arbitration - is a high-z state used to determine if the line is free? what about the active low line? Is line arbitration even possible? On second thought, I don't even think it's possible to do arbitration on the lines, there would need to be some kind of decided-beforehand timing so that arbitration isn't necessary?

How does termination work? I'm inclined to think the same resistors on both ends won't work? And neither will no resistors? Does the resistance on either end have to be switched in or out dynamically depending on who is driving?

EDIT: Extra questions/clarifications:

How prevalent is this kind of interface?  Is it specific to SDRAM (or this specific chip?) or does it occur regularly in other scenarios? I'm particularly looking for some kind of hardware interface standard, if one exists, rather than trying to extract the interface info from my sdram datasheet (unless of course this is device/manufacturer specific).

Answer (score 1):

> How exactly does this work? Particularly line arbitration

From p. 10 of the datasheet, "DQS is a strobe transmitted by the DDR2 SDRAM during READs and by the memory controller during WRITEs"

Timing diagrams on p. 78, p. 82, and elsewhere show more details of how the signals are used. Basically the DQS lines are kept in high-Z until the type of transaction has been determined and it's known which chip will drive the line.

> How does termination work? I'm inclined to think the same resistors on both ends won't work? Does the resistance on either end have to be switched in or out dynamically depending on who is driving?

From p. 81 of the datasheet, see that there is a programmable on-die termination provided, and that this termination is required to be turned off for some states of the memory chip.

100 Ohm differential (or whatever matches the line impedance) at each end of the line should work for a point to point link. When one end is driving, the driver will be a low impedance source, so the termination resistor on that end won't affect signal propagation on the line, though it will force the driver to source more current in order to drive the line.

Where things get hairy is if you want to have multiple memory chips connected to the same signal lines. I've seen this done, with the two memories belly-to-belly on either side of the PCB, to minimize the stubs when either memory was driving the lines. I don't recall if that was a DDR2 or DDR3 design, and I have no idea whether the design was marginally functional or total overkill.  If you need 3 or more memories on the same bus, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I did see the timing diagrams, but didn't know that the line halfway between high and low was considered high impedance. So if I want to turn the ODT off, I can just terminate both sides with 100 ohms and that will work?

Comment: Assuming the other end of your link (FPGA or uP?) can handle the extra load, it sounds good to me. Maybe check if Micron or your FPGA vendor has any app notes on layout for DDR2/3?